# Renaming keys in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

Lets say i want to change the key "c3" to a variable x = "b2" and keep the value of the key itself, so it should look like this: "b2": "example3".

```
var x = {
                "a1": "example1",
                "b2": "example2",
                "c3": "example3"
        };
```

Also, are there "better" types of arrays, that would go through all keys in this array just fine with 
a

for ( var a in x ) loop?

Comment: Javascript basics here.  The `{"a1": "example1"}` syntax is a Javascript object, NOT an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot change the value of a key in javascript object.  Instead, you can assign a new key and then remove the prior key:

```
var x = {
    "a1": "example1",
    "b2": "example2",
    "c3": "example3"
};

// assign new key with value of prior key
x["a2"] = x["a1"];

// remove prior key
delete x["a1"];
```

---

And, please understand that these are NOT arrays.  These are Javascript objects.  An array is a different type of data structure.

The syntax `for (var key in x)` is the usual way to iterate properties of an object.  Here's a summary of several different approaches:

```
// iterate all enumerable properties, including any on the prototype
for (var key in x) {
    console.log(key +", " + x[key]);
}

// iterate all enumerable properties, directly on the object (not on the prototype)
for (var key in x) {
    if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key +", " + x[key]);
    }
}

// get an array of the keys and enumerate that
var keys = Object.keys(x);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log(keys[i] +", " + x[keys[i]]);
}
```